# bind () to an IPv6 address in windows 7 is Failing with Error code :: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL (10049)

Tags: windows-7, bind, ipv6

I am trying to set-up a private ipv6 network with two windows-7 machines for tesing my application. I have written a sample code to test the socket apis. I have created an IPv6 socket. When I try to *bind* with  the link-local address (which I get from *ipconfig* command), the error code is 10049.

Please inform, why the *bind* with Ipv6 address is failing in windows-7 machine ?

Comment: Can you post a small code sample that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a link-local IPv6 address, you probably need to set the `sin6_scope_id` field in your `sockaddr_in6` structure to indicate which interface you want to listen on. A link-local address is ambiguous, since [every interface must have a link-local address assigned](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.1), and they all use the same prefix. (`fe80::/64`)

You should probably `bind()` your listen socket to the unspecified address (all-zeroes or `::`) so this isn't an issue, but it will still be a problem for the sending side. If you don't specify the `sin6_scope_id`, the system won't know which interface to send the packet on.

To avoid the issue, it would be best to set up an IPv6 router that does [router advertisements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862), so you can get [global unicast](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.4) (or, at a minimum, [unique local](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193)) addresses.