# sendto() has different behavior for IPv4 & IPv6 when send datagram to unreachable destination

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

When I use `sendto()` to send a datagram to a non-existing destination, I found that the result is different for IPv4 and IPv6.

- IPv4:
  It just returns a positive value.
- IPv6:
  It returns `-1` with `errno` set to `ENETUNREACH`

Does anyone know why this happen?

## Here's my code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Usage: program [version]
    int version = argc == 1 ? 4 : atoi(argv[1]);

    int fd = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (fd == -1)
        ErrAndExit ("socket");

    if (version == 4) // use ipv4
    {
        struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
        memset (&srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr));
        srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        srv_addr.sin_port = htons (11111);
        if (inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.0.200", &srv_addr.sin_addr) != 1)
            ErrAndExit ("inet_pton");

        socklen_t len = sizeof(srv_addr);
        puts("going to sendto...");
        ssize_t res = sendto (fd, "hello", 6, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_addr, len);
        if (res == -1)
            ErrAndExit("sendto");

        printf ("done with res: %ld\n", res);
    }
    else // use ipv6
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 srv_addr;
        memset (&srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr));
        srv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        srv_addr.sin6_port = htons (11111);
        if (inet_pton (AF_INET6, "2002::148:249", &srv_addr.sin6_addr) != 1)
            ErrAndExit ("inet_pton");

        socklen_t len = sizeof(srv_addr);
        puts("going to sendto...");
        ssize_t res = sendto (fd, "hello", 6, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_addr, len);
        if (res == -1)
            ErrAndExit("sendto");

        printf ("done with res: %ld\n", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sending to an IPv6 address that your box has a route for ? You likely have all routes(because you have a default route) for IPv4, but do you for your IPv6 address ?

Comment: Do you have at least one interface with a IPv6 binded?

Comment: Your socket is created with AF_INET6, but you use that same socket to sent to an IPv4 address (sockaddr_in).  Is this allowed in IPv6 sockets? Is suspect the address is translated, but I didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising that IPv6 can give you an error, not that IPv4 can't. IPv4 normally only delivers errors to *connected* UDP sockets.

Comment: I suspect you can get an early failure if there's no route present for  the destination host in your local routing tables.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me when the `srv_addr.sin6_scope` value was incorrect.

Some more information about using sin6_scope ID in other questions: 
[Adding support for IPv6 in IPv4 client/server apps - sin6_flowinfo and sin6_scope_id fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256671/adding-support-for-ipv6-in-ipv4-client-server-apps-sin6-flowinfo-and-sin6-scop)